# I wrote an english to pig latin converter and even though it compiles properly it says it terminated after it threw an instance of 'std: :out of range

Tags: c++

I'm working on a english to pig-latin converter as a project to learn basic c++ with, and for some reason even though it compiles correctly it says it terminated. here's the console output:

```
input a word. 
hello
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::insert: __pos (which is 5) > this->size() (which is 4)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

this is the full program code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 //get's user input and assigns it as input
    string input;
    cout << "input a word. " << endl;
    getline(cin,input);

//defines output
    string output = input.assign(input);

//reads length of the input
    int length = input.size();

//get's the first letter of input and set's firstLetter to be that letter
    string firstLetter = input.assign(input,0,1);

    bool firstLetterIsVowel = true;

//see's if first letter is a vowel
    if ((firstLetter == "a") || (firstLetter == "e") || (firstLetter == "E") || (firstLetter == "i") || (firstLetter == "I") || (firstLetter == "o") || (firstLetter == "O") || (firstLetter == "u") || (firstLetter == "U"))
    {
        firstLetterIsVowel = true;
    }
    else
    {
        firstLetterIsVowel = false;
    }

//converts to pig latin
    if (firstLetterIsVowel == false)
    {
        output.erase(0,1);

        output.insert(length,firstLetter);

        output.insert(length + 1,"ay");
    }

    else if (firstLetterIsVowel == true)
    {
        output.insert((length) + 1,"way");
    }

    cout << output << endl;




    return 0;
}
```

what exactly is the issue?

Comment: Note: Compilation only means your program is syntactically correct. Watch a few infomercials or political debates and you'll quickly see that things can be grammatically correct still be logically questionable.

Answer (score 1):

After `output.erase(0,1)`, the length of `output` is `length-1`. Then `output.insert(length,firstLetter)` specifies an index out of bounds.

If you want to append to the end of the string, there's `append` method.